# Vector clocks: Why is it necessary to increment my clock on receiving a message?

Tags: distributed-systems, synchronization, clocks

Assume I have a distributed system of entities, each with a replica of the same data object that can be modified by broadcasting the changes and I'm using vector clocks to know how to order changes.

In this scenario, Why would I need to increment my own clock if I receive an update? (I noticed [in the original paper on vector clocks](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs426/2012/lab/bib/fidge88timestamps.pdf), they didn't mention this rule, yet followed it in the examples...) Would it be sufficient if I only incremented my clock when **I** change the data object?

Comment: Actually my question is about version vectors, which don't require incrementing your own clock upon applying an update.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the definition of $<_H$.

We say that $e_1<_H e_2$ (event 1 happened before event 2) if:

1. $e_1,e_2$ took place in the same process, and $e_1$ happened first (events within the same process are ordered).
2. $e_1,e_2$ are the sending and receiving of some message $m$, correspondingly.

Finally, we take the transitive closure of the above, and this yield Lamport's happened before relation.

Our objective is to assign time stamps to events, $T_{e_i}$ with a partial order $<_t$, such that $e_1<_H e_2 \iff T_{e_1}<_t T_{e_2}$.

The timestamps suggested here are vectors in $\mathbb{N}^n$, with the ordering $T_{e_p}<_t T_{e_q} \iff T_{e_p}[p]<T_{e_q}[p]$ where $e_p,e_q$ are events in processes $p,q$ correspondingly (assume each time stamp contains the process id).

Back to your question, not updating your clock upon receiving a message would cause your new relation $<_t$ to disagree with $<_H$ in events within the same process. For example, you would have $c\not\rightarrow d$ (figure 3). In addition, this is mentioned in the paper (rule 2, increase the local clock at each atomic event, which is either sending or receiving a message).

Comment: Mh, the paper's definition of the partial ordering is different from the one on wikipedia :/

It appears in the paper only the p component is compared and needs to be strictly less, while [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock#Partial_ordering_property) all components must be less or equal and one must be strictly less.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem. It seems my feeling was correct: [Version vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_vector) are updated upon local changes (by incrementing the local counter) and upon receiving remote changes by using max() for all values.

Comment: @MarcelKlehr It seems like you're confusing Version Vectors with Vector Clocks. For more informatio, see https://haslab.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/version-vectors-are-not-vector-clocks/.